# Wrong rendering of inconsalata in terminator

Tags: gnome-terminal, fonts, terminator

These are two consecutive screenshots of the terminator window with inconsalata font

[image]
[image]

the issue is that : . ! don't get rendered normally the first time and these chars are almost invisible while normally typing.

Any action (taking a screenshot, resize, just focus out and back in) will make all characters look normal.

I really like the Inconsalata font and this is really makes it unusable.

Any ideas or dirty hacks would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:

and in gnome-terminal
[image]

EDIT2: only happens on a 4k display.

Comment: Does it happen with gnome-terminal too?

Comment: I just tried it and yes, it does.

Comment: How did you install the font (e.g. from [here](http://www.levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html), [google fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Inconsolata) etc), and what formats are installed?

Comment: I just installed ttf-inconsolata with the packet manager. I also added "!" in gnome terminal to the description.

Comment: Note that some shells cause problems with font rendering not because of the font itself, but because of environment settings, left over color settings, etc.  It may not be that the font is actually at fault at all.

Comment: @ThomasW. But it's the same with Terminator and Gnome-terminal and no matter what other settings I try.

Comment: I should also point out you give us no version information. I can't reproduce in 14.04, and it could be all that color you have in there breaking rendering.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite possible that one in the 'package' is a little funky and may not be the font you actually want, which was the case with me. So, I solved this by manually installing the font in my user space.  Note that I prefer [Inconsolata-dz](http://nodnod.net/2009/feb/12/adding-straight-single-and-double-quotes-inconsola/) to pure Inconsolata, if only because of straight format single and double quotes.

---

First, let's set up the directory we need.  `mkdir -p /home/$USER/.local/share/fonts/`.  We'll put the font here for use.

Secondly, download the font.  [Here](http://www.levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html) and [here (Google Fonts)](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Inconsolata) are such download locations.

Finally, get the font file out of the downloaded files (probably it's inside a ZIP file), and put it into `/home/$USER/.local/share/fonts/`.  That will make it available to your user for use.

Comment: I tried this and it makes no difference. I also tried Inconsalata-g and other variations, and I'm thinking the file is not in the font, as much as in the rendering.